# Structure meteor packages in subfolders

Tags: meteor, meteor-packages

I have started a Meteor app with packages to isolate my functionality, the problem is that we have a lot of `packages` and all are placed in the packages folder without any hierarchy.

Placing this packages in subfolders would cause meteor not to find the dependency, is there a way to correctly organize this packages?

Comment: I'd like that too, however as noted in [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4534), meteor only supports a flat list.

Comment: @DavidWeldon The workaround indicated by Slava is pretty nice. Does it still work as of today?

Comment: I haven't tried. For me, I'm not sure that's a practical workaround.

Comment: I haven't found a solution either, but if you're looking to just make it easier to read, I use this approach https://github.com/thatgibbyguy/tgg-meteor-boilerplate/blob/master/app/.meteor/packages

Answer (score -1):

We found, that it is better not to use the .meteor/packages file, instead we are including all packages we need in a custom package with our own structure.

`.meteor/packages` includes only => `acme:app`

`acme:app` use => `acme:xyz`,`acme:xxx`
`acme:xyz` use => `acme:base`
`acme:xxx` use => `acme:base`

`acme:base` use => `meteor-base`, `mongo`, `meteorhacks:flow-router`, `...`

in `acme:app` we are loading all our custom packages, which are depending on the `acme:base` package, and in `acme:base` we are loading all core the third party libraries.

Comment: Question is about `packages` folder, not file.

Comment: your are right, it was just an suggestion to structure packages not a solution for subfolders

Comment: but.. read the last question "how to organize packages" so it is not wrong to mention our solution here ;)